# Count of records from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two Tables named SavingAccountTransactions and LoanAccountTransactions.

Both the tables are having same columns (fk_MemberId,fk_AgentId,TransactionDate)

Sample Data

**SavingAccountTransactions Table**

```
Id   fk_MemberId    fk_AgentId   TransactionDate  Amount
---  -----------    -----------  ---------------  -------
1      441             12           2014-12-30      100
2      452             6            2014-12-30      300
```

**LoanAccountTransactions Table**

```
Id   fk_MemberId    fk_AgentId   TransactionDate  Amount
---  -----------    -----------  ---------------  -------
1      441             12           2014-12-30      500
2      452             6            2014-12-30      200
```

How can i combine SavingAccountTransactions and LoanAccountTransactions tables to get the count of **NoOfMembersVisited**  in a single row for particular member.

Below is the query which i have tried

```
select u.Fullname as AgentName ,count (distinct t.fk_MemberId ) as NoOfMembersVisited
from dbo.SavingAccountTransactions T
inner join Users u on t.fk_AgentId=u.Id
where t.TransactionDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)                                                         
group by u.Fullname
Union all
select u.Fullname as AgentName, count (distinct l.fk_MemberId ) as NoOfMembersVisited
from  LoanAccountTransactions L
inner join Users u on L.fk_AgentId=u.Id
where l.TransactionDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
group by u.Fullname
```

Expected Result:

```
AgentName  NoOfMembersVisited
---------  -------------------
John             2
Kevin            1

etc....
```

Comment: Please, provide table schema and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not provided any sample data it is hard to know what you are getting. But I might have an idea what you problem is. When you use the `UNION ALL` the users get repeated if they are in both of the table. Because it might be different counts from the tables changing the `UNION ALL` to `UNION` will not work. I would like to suggest you to do something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    select u.Fullname as AgentName,l.fk_MemberId
    from dbo.SavingAccountTransactions T
    inner join Users u on t.fk_AgentId=u.Id
    where t.TransactionDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
    UNION ALL
    select u.Fullname as AgentName,l.fk_MemberId
    from  LoanAccountTransactions L
    inner join Users u on L.fk_AgentId=u.Id
    where l.TransactionDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
)
SELECT
    CTE.Fullname,
    COUNT(distinct CTE.fk_MemberId) as NoOfMembersVisited
FROM
    CTE
group by
    CTE.Fullname
```